# Trigger number bar android keyboard

Tags: php, android, html

Google have updated android keyboard to v5 which automatically shows a number bar when you enter a password field.

[image: Android Keyboard v5]

Is there a way to trigger this number bar to appear from non-password fields? It would be very useful to trigger on fields that require e.g. a zip/postal code to be entered.

e.g.

`<input type="text" name="postcode" number-bar>` ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the type to number

```
<input type="number" >
```

https://jsfiddle.net/z5g94c67/

Type=text does both ( at least on a samsung note 5 )

[image]

Comment: I don't want the field to be a number input... I would like to use it in a zip/postal code field.

Comment: type="text" shoud do it with both the numbers and letters, https://jsfiddle.net/2zewy1pj/ , it at least does on my phone